# Using the DD command, Linux

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, dd, sd-card, cloning

I want to use `dd` to clone my running Linux OS which is installed on a PI4 MicroSD 64GB media, to an image.  Because it is a Raspberry PI I cannot (easily) boot from a USB stick and run the job with the PI4 OS not running. If I do such a job, using a console login, can I restore later without issue?  Essentially can `dd` create a proper, restorable image of the main drive (/dev/sda) from a terminal session from within a running system?

Comment: Theoretically, it depends on whether the disk is writing or not. Why not just plug that disk onto a computer and dd it off-line?

Comment: Thank you.  I did not have that option initially because it is a MicroSD but I can borrow a Card Reader and do what you say.  I wanted to see if 'dd' could replace 'dump' or 'cpio' on a live system, by some means.

Comment: I had thought that being at runlevel 1 might lower the Disk activity, particularly writing.  Thanks...

Comment: dd is usually not a good option. Depending on what you want, you might want tar to make an file-based archive instead of block-based byte-by-byte copy. If you really need that, you can use bash as your init, so no other process would be writing to disk, but notice that bash itself also store .bash_history on disk, so this still cause data corruption

Comment: while dump And cpio or tar are file based, as long as the file being backed up isn't being written, you'll be fine, there's usually options allowing you to skip unimportant files, like /tmp

Comment: Does your question **have to** be solved with `dd`, or can we use `pv`, and possibly other utilities, please clarify this in your question. Cheers.

Comment: None of `pv` and `dd` have a final checkpoint, where the user can double-check, that the choice of target device is correct. The cloning process itself is robust, but too often I have seen cases, when valuable data have been overwritten. There is a reason for the nicknames Data Destroyer and Disk Destroyer for `dd` because it  does what you tell it to do without any question. There are other tools (not only with GUI but also in text mode) with a final checkpoint and some extra output to help identify and select the correct target device.

Answer (score 4):

There are two general types of methods how you can clone GNU/Linux to another hard drive, an SD card or a floppy. The first is when you clone a whole file system with everything it contains and when you copy all required files of your system and configure it to work somewhere else.

### The first type: clone the whole file system

dd is the most reliable and old-fashioned way to clone the whole file system. If you want to make an image of your entire disk with all partitions in it you can simply execute in your terminal

```
dd if=/dev/sdX of=/path/backup_sdX.img
```

and then

```
dd if=/path/backup_sdX.img of=/dev/sdY
```

to deploy your image on `sdY` disk. It may require `sudo`. backup_sdX.img will have the same size as the whole `sdX`. Use `lsblk` to figure out `sdX` and `sdY`.

> Be careful with dd command. It may irreversibly erase your operating system and all your data.

dd doesn't have a verbose option and you might want to see progress of dd with pipe data monitor [pv](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pv.1.html). Make sure you've installed pv (for Debian or Ubuntu)

```
sudo apt-get install pv

pv /dev/sdX | dd of=/path/backup_sdX.img
```

It may require `sudo` before `pv` and `dd` command. If you have SSH access from your Raspberry PI to another machine, then you can do

```
dd if=/dev/sdX | ssh username@hostname "dd of=/path/backup_sdX.img"
```

or

```
pv /dev/sdX | ssh username@hostname "dd of=/path/backup_sdX.img"
```

to see progress. hostname could be a local IP address of another machine. Make sure you have enough space on your receiving size because file.img will be the same size as your whole sdX disk.

You can even mount your image to your system.

```
sudo mount /path/backup_sdX.img /mnt
```

which could be helpful if you want to change something. If it won't work for some reason try [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/69363/mount-single-partition-from-image-of-entire-disk-device).

Why you might dislike this method:

- It may take a long time to copy each block of your disk, especially if that disk is huge.
- `sdY` should have a bigger size than `sdX`.
- `sdY` will have the same partitions of `sdX` and will be simply resized to sdX (of course you can fix that later but with a risk to lose your data).
- You could be very disappointed if you mix up with `sdY`.

Once you understand all the advantages and disadvantages of using `dd` command, you would probably want to try something more specific as `clonezilla`, `partclone`, or `partimage`.

---

### The second type: copy and configure

Simply clone the required files of your operating system and configure it. This is a much more advanced way to clone a system.

- make partitions on your target hard drive with `gparted`, `parted` or any other program
- mount all required partitions
- transfer files using `rsync` which could be done via SSH or just DHCP network locally
- change /etc/fstab
- install or update grub or configure uefi (if you use it) though `chroot`

A good guide on how to do this could be found [here](http://positon.org/clone-a-linux-system-install-to-another-computer).

Comment: Concerning your remark "`dd` doesn't have a verbose option and you might want to see progress of `dd` with pipe data monitor `pv`." -- there is an improved version of `dd` called `dcfldd` which is available (at least) on Debian-based distributions and has enhanced output options, including status updates. Otherwise: nice answer!

Comment: Thank you Ivan.

Comment: I have used 'dd' to clone 'offline' drives and partitions.  I was wondering if there was a way to use it on a running system.  I can see that it is primarily for 'offline' media.  I do not use LVM and only ext[3,4] filesystems.  Thank you very much for your post.  I will keep it for my usage as it is so thorough.  :-)

Comment: Don't bother with `dd`, especially as you're using 512 byte blocks, so generating 8 writes per SDD block. Just use `cat`.

Comment: I just used dd on a running system. My usb floppy with working Debian and the whole root partition encrypted with luks was successfully cloned. Everything including luks encryption is working fine. The whole process took around 2 hours because of very slow speed of 32 Gb floppy disk (a few Mb per second). I'd use ssh in your case and leave it for a night.

Comment: *dd is the most reliable*... eh, really? Being one of the oldest utilities does not make it *the best option*, it merely states you *prefer* that utility. I'd recommend cutting this sentence out of your answer.

Comment: @roaima Why would anyone like *not to see the progress*? Did I misunderstand your comment or were you really suggesting `cat /dev/disk/...`?

Comment: Regarding the second type as you called it, which starts with *Simply*... there is nothing close to simple with that method, please read your words again and if you find my suggestion constructive, adjust the text of your answer. Cheers.

Comment: And my last comment will be in regard to *If it won't work for some reason try this.*, of course `mount` without `offset` option will not work if making an image of the whole disk. Was that rhetorical? I suppose I have to vote down now, will get back in the evening to check upon your changes, if there will be any, and might reverse it, ok? Good luck, and welcome to U&L family!

Comment: Why did you combine `pv` with `dd`? That's not good. `pv` can be used to do this completely alone: `pv < /dev/sdX > /dev/sdY`. Or store the disk to a file first, of course, the syntax is universal. Have fun.

Comment: To speed up `dd`, you man want to use its option `bs` which defaults to 512 bytes. You can set it to whatever amount of memory you can spend, e.g. `bs=100M` to make the buffer 100 Megabytes large.

Comment: @LinuxSecurityFreak you understood me correctly. `cat /dev/sda >/dev/sdb` is always faster than plain `dd` and rarely slower than `dd bs=...` variants.

Comment: @roaima Ok, well, you are correct there. I avoid `dd` for performance reasons too. But I personally prefer seeing a progress bar and time estimate, which is why I recommend `pv` whenever possible. Cheers!