# Clone partitions and content of an SD card onto another one

Tags: partition, file-copy, sd-card, partition-table

Let's assume that I have an SD card with different partitions and files or filesystems on them and I want to reproduce it on another non-partitioned SD card (the new card will be of the same size). Is there a command or set of commands that could be put together in a bash script to automate the process?
So far I can only copy the content of one partition with the `dd` command.

Comment: Just copy the whole disk (with dd).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the DD command, Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/553059/using-the-dd-command-linux)

Comment: This is one you could easily Google. `dd` is considered the canonical way. By the way, you can just copy (`cp` from one block device to another). `cp /dev/mmcblk0 /dev/mmcblk1`.